# lazyRegister: max possible with nested elements or iron pages?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.0

Is it possible to `lazyRegister: max` with:

1) nesting elements in parent`my-app` element?

2) nesting elements in iron-pages?

I have a `console.log` statement in element `single-listing` that fires when `attached` is ran... which does it right away when the app loads. So, `lazyRegister` is not working for me.

```
<script>
  // Setup Polymer options
  window.Polymer = {
    dom: 'shadow',
    lazyRegister: 'max'
  };

 ...
 <my-app></my-app>
```

---

my-app.html:

```
    <!-- Main content -->
    <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
      <user-login data-route="user-login"></user-login>
      <my-view1 data-route="my-view1" form-loading="{{isLoading}}"
        listings="[[listings]]" tabindex="-1"></my-view1>
      <single-listing data-route="single-listing"></single-listing>
      <my-view3 data-route="my-view3"></my-view3>
    </iron-pages>
```

---

single-listing.html:

```
  attached: function() {
    this.async(()=> {
      console.log('foo') })
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to `lazyRegister: max` with nesting elements [...]?

Yes, this is possible, as can be seen in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/g3UCLtqXXWITRMbWFLBR?p=preview).

*Plunker note:* There's a delay in Plunker before registering `x-el`, so wait a few seconds after "Hello world" appears before checking the console, which should display `x-el attached`:

[image: screenshot]

> `lazyRegister` is not working for me

I think you might be misunderstanding the purpose of that flag, and when registration occurs. The flag defers element registration until the element is created. You can create an element declaratively (i.e., by writing "`<lazy-element>`" in HTML) or imperatively (i.e., `document.create('lazy-element');` in JavaScript).

In your example, you've declared the element, which effectively creates it, so the registration occurs when the host of the element is created. In the following example snippet, `<lazy-element>` is created when `<my-app>` is created, which is when `<my-app>`'s definition is imported.

```
<!-- my-app.html -->
<my-app>
  <iron-pages>
    <lazy-element></lazy-element>
  </iron-pages>
</my-app>
```

If you want to defer element creation until the page is selected, you could lazy-load the element's import using one of the following methods (and remove `lazyRegister` flag, as it would be redundant):

- [`this.importHref('lazy-element.html')`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/instance-methods#imports-and-urls) (*See how [Polymer Starter Kit](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/2a02784/src/my-app.html#L130) does it*)
- [`<iron-lazy-pages>`](https://github.com/TimvdLippe/iron-lazy-pages)
- [`<lazy-imports>`](https://github.com/Polymer/lazy-imports)

Comment: In my situation, why is `console.log('foo')` running when I have not clicked on the iron-page selection `<single-listing></single-listing>`? Because of `lazyRegister: max` shouldn't the element not be registered until I click on the iron-page selection?

Comment: `defers element registration until the element is created.`... wouldn't this be the default behavior since the element has to be created first anyways? Otherwise, it can't register a element that doesn't exist.

Comment: No, you can declare the element before it's created (see my answer for definition of "created"). For example, you enabled `lazyRegister` and imported `paper-input/paper-input.html`, but `<paper-input>` does not exist in the current document and your JS has no calls to `document.create()`. So, `<paper-input>` is not registered. Now, let's say you have a button that dynamically adds a `<paper-input>` to the document with `document.create('paper-input')` and `document.body.append()`. Clicking that button would include registering the element, since it's the first time the element is created.